# okta Angular 7 oktaAuth.isAuthenticated() is false even after successfully logging in

Tags: angular, okta

I am trying to work through this demo: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/12/04/angular-7-oidc-oauth2-pkce#upgrade-to-angular-7
This is one of a few tutorials which I have gone through and I keep on getting the same results

Even after I successfully log into Okta oktaAuth.isAuthenticated() is still set to false.

I know I am successfully logging in because the dashboard says I was successful and when I try to log in again I don't get redirected to the Sign In Page.

Here is my code:

**app.component.html**

```
<h1>Welcome to {{ title }}!</h1>

<div *ngIf="isAuthenticated">
  <!-- <h2>Hi, {{user?.name}}!</h2> -->
  <button (click)="oktaAuth.logout()">Logout</button>
</div>

<div *ngIf="!isAuthenticated">
  <button (click)="oktaAuth.loginRedirect()">Login</button>
</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { OktaAuthService, UserClaims } from '@okta/okta-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'ng-secure';
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
  email: string;

  constructor(public oktaAuth: OktaAuthService) {
  }

  async ngOnInit() {
    this.isAuthenticated = await this.oktaAuth.isAuthenticated();
           // Subscribe to authentication state changes
    this.oktaAuth.$authenticationState.subscribe( async(isAuthenticated: boolean)  => {
      this.isAuthenticated = isAuthenticated;
              });
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
//import { OAuthModule } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';

import { OktaAuthModule } from '@okta/okta-angular';

const config = {
  issuer: 'https://dev-xxxxxx.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default',
  redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/implicit/callback',
  clientId: 'Correct Client Id'
};


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    //OAuthModule.forRoot()
    OktaAuthModule.initAuth(config)


  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { OktaCallbackComponent } from '@okta/okta-angular';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'implicit/callback',
    component: OktaCallbackComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Is there another flag besides oktaAuth.isAuthenticated() to indicate that I am successfully logged in?

Thanks for your help.

I was able to get the okta-hosted-login example running which is provided by okta. However, this app is in Angular 5.

One thing I found interesting is if I try to log in using my Angular 7 app, I get the following error message:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://dev-979343.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/.well-known/openid-configuration' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I don't get this CORS error when I ues the okta-hosted-login Angular 5

Comment: Are you getting auth state changes? I mean, if you console.log `isAuthenticated` inside the subscription, is its value changing? Also, you may remove `async` from the subscribe function, as no `await` is being used inside it.

Comment: What is your issuer set to? I want to make sure you’re using the right one.

Comment: GCSDC per your suggestion updated the ngOnInit.  isAuthenticated is set to false. However, like I mentioned above, I know I successfully logged in based on the okta portal and the fact I am not prompted to log in again.

Comment: Matt. Thanks for following up.  My issuer is correct. I know this since I am redirected to my okta sign in page.

Comment: @MattRaible do you have a git repo with the source code from you post?

Comment: Here’s a blog post for Angular 7 + Spring Boot. You can find a GitHub repo at the end. https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/08/22/basic-crud-angular-7-and-spring-boot-2

Comment: @MattRaible Thanks but I was asking about a git repo with the source code which is referenced in this post:  https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/12/04/angular-7-oidc-oauth2-pkce#upgrade-to-angular-7 The one I mentioned above. I have no idea what Spring Boot is.  But I will try to review the link you provided.

Comment: I did not create a repo for those examples. I did create a new way for you to easily add Okta to an Angular app though. See https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/02/13/angular-schematics. It condenses 7 steps to 1: `ng add @oktadev/schematics`

Comment: @MattRaible Ok I will take a look.  Thanks

Comment: @MattRaible I made some progress and learned a few things. I did your schematics demo (very easy).  I was able to successfully log in and when I redirected back to the home page the LogIn button was hidden. (*ngIf="!isAuthenticated") So, I thought I was good.  But, after reviewing the code I saw a LogOut button should be shown if the user isAuthenticated (*ngIf="isAuthenticated") However I never see the LogOut button.  Any ideas?  I tried a few things and ever recreated the Ng App.  Please let me know.  Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real issue was related to this post: [okta Angular 7 App returning a CORS error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55661247/okta-angular-7-app-returning-a-cors-error)

With the help of @MattRaible pointing me to the right direction I was able to resolve this issue. Basically, I didn't have authority to add a Trusted Origin (menu item API | Trusted Origin) on the okta site. Once an administrator added ‘http://localhost:4200’ as a Trusted Origin everything started working.

Thanks to everyone who commented on this post.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was that this.oktaAuth.tokenManager that I was calling .get("accessToken") on didn't have an accessToken property yet because that is added in the handleAuthentication() method that does

```
this.oktaAuth.tokenManager.add(
      "accessToken",
      tokenContainer.tokens.accessToken as AccessToken
    );
```

Which wasn't being called by default as part of the login method, it was only called with the /callback route. And when I tried to call /callback directly I didn't have the token appended to the request so it was failing as well. So just make sure you add accessToken to the object before you call isAuthenticated()

I was working off of this example: https://developer.okta.com/code/angular/okta_angular_auth_js/ from developer.okta.com