# okta Angular 7 App returning a CORS error

Tags: angular, okta

I am currently working through this demo:
https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/12/04/angular-7-oidc-oauth2-pkce

I am setting up the OIDC Version

I am getting the following error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   ‘https://dev-979343.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/.well-known/openid-configuration’ from origin ‘http://localhost:4200’ has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   No ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ header is present on the requested
>   resource.

I have been playing around with this off and on for the last 3 days and I can't seem to get it to work.

I am using Angular version 7.1 (Just like the demo)

Here is my code:

**app.component.html**

```
<h1>Welcome to {{ title }}!</h1>

<div *ngIf="givenName">
  <h2>Hi, {{givenName}}!</h2>
  <button (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
</div>

<div *ngIf="!givenName">
  <button (click)="login()">Login</button>
</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { OAuthService, JwksValidationHandler, AuthConfig } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';

export const authConfig: AuthConfig = {
  issuer: 'https://dev-979343.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default',
  redirectUri: window.location.origin,
  clientId: '0oaka2hty7eVrwEHS0h7'
};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'ng-secure';

  constructor(private oauthService: OAuthService) {
    this.oauthService.configure(authConfig);
    this.oauthService.tokenValidationHandler = new JwksValidationHandler();
    this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocumentAndTryLogin();
  }

  login() {
    this.oauthService.initImplicitFlow();
  }

  logout() {
    this.oauthService.logOut();
  }

  get givenName() {
    const claims = this.oauthService.getIdentityClaims();
    if (!claims) {
      return null;
    }
    return claims['name'];
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { OAuthModule } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    OAuthModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you try adding http://localhost:4200 as a Trusted Origin under the API menu (on Okta)?

Comment: I found a post that mentioned that suggestions earlier.  When I go to API | Trusted Origins I get a 403 Access Forbidden.  Do I need special authority to access this menu option?

Comment: If you created your org, it should be available to the account you created it with. You can always create a new one at http://developer.okta.com/signup/. Then you'll have access to this menu item.

Comment: @MattRaible Short Story:  That fixed my problem.  Long Story: I did not create the org. I will have to follow up with the individual(s) in my company that did. However, I did create a new one and that worked.  Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of @MattRaible pointing me to the right direction I was able to resolve this issue.  Basically, I didn't have authority to add a Trusted Origin (menu item API | Trusted Origin) on the okta site. Once an administrator added ‘http://localhost:4200’ as a Trusted Origin everything started working.

Thanks to everyone who commented on this post.

Answer (score 1):

All you would need to do is send `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'` along with the request in your angular service file. I have shown below a way to do this. This simply modifies the server to add the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * to enable cross-origin requests from anywhere.

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
    'Authorization':'authkey',
    'userid':'1'
  })
};

public baseurl = 'http://localhost/XXXXXX';

userAPI(data): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post(this.baseurl, data, httpOptions)**// Pass in the options in the request**
    .pipe(
      tap((result) => console.log('result-->',result)),
      catchError(this.handleError('error', []))
    );
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

From the [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) definition in Mozilla.

> A web application executes a cross-origin HTTP request when it requests a resource that has a different origin (domain, protocol, and port) than its own origin.

So for your request to work, you have two options:

1. Add an 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header to your API's response with a value of your ip ie. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "172.168.1.1"`
2. Add your external IP Address to the Allowed addresses via the Okta interface if you have access to it. Check [here](https://developer.okta.com/docs/api/getting_started/enabling_cors/).

You can view your external ip address via website that let you view them. Try to check yours at [Cmyip](https://www.cmyip.com).

Comment: Thanks. I don't really understand what you are suggesting.  So, I will have to investigate how to do this.  Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @Richard here you go https://developer.okta.com/docs/api/getting_started/enabling_cors/

Answer (score 0):

```
https://dev-979343.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

is a *redirect URL* so you gotta redirect, **don't use XMLHttpRequest**. You can test this by simply pasting the above URL to the browser. As you can see, it gives you the data you looking for.